# Query firestore in flutter: permission denied, what to do

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to query some data from private devices. My rules are set as following:

```
match /private_devices/{device} {
      function userHasKey() {
         return request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/keys/$(device));
      }
          
      allow read: if (userHasKey())
}
```

My flutter code:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getPrivateDevices(List<String> keyList) {
     return private.where('UDID', whereIn: keyList).snapshots();
}
```

I use a list to import the keys from:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUserKeys(User user) {
     return users.document(user.uid).collection('keys').snapshots();
}
```

And my user rules:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read, write: if (request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId)
}
        
match /users/{userId}/keys/{key} {
    allow read, write: if (request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId)
}
```

Edit: my collection references:

```
final CollectionReference devices = Firestore.instance.collection("devices");
final CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection("users");
final CollectionReference private = Firestore.instance.collection("private_devices");
```

I get a following permission error in my console:

```
Listen for Query(private_devices where UDID in [F8MXi2JzwYvIAoVRYG5f] order by __name__) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/System.out(27625): com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I also tested my rules in the rules playground, and everything worked fine. I know it has to do with querying, but have no clue how to progress forward.

I have also noticed that when i try to get a single document with `private.document(keyList[0]).get()`, I actually get back the data.

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: There's not enough code here to see what your actual queries are.  Please show the **full** queries, which lets us see how they map to the rules you've defined.  We just can't tell if your queries actually match the rules.

Comment: There are no other queries for this. Just collection references.

Comment: In any event, show the complete code. There's not enough information here.  For example, we can't see what `private` and `users` are in your code.  There should be enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I have added every line that is referenced to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules don't allow the query because [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).  Be sure to read that documentation carefully, as well as [this blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

Security rules are not going to cross-reference another document for each document in the query result.  That just doesn't scale in the way that Firestore requires.  You **can** do that for individual document gets, but not for queries.

What you will have to do instead is put all of the data necessary for the filter into documents in a single collection, and make sure the client is applying a filter that matches only the documents they are allowed to read by the rule.